# Why isn't python finding the cwiid module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, raspberry-pi, wii

I installed cwiid to my raspberry pi 4 
(`sudo apt-get install python-cwiid`)
and it worked, but when I try to import it into a python file
`import cwiid`, it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cwiid'
(I've also tried `import python-cwiid` but that gave me a syntax error)

Comment: Have you tried running it sans `sudo`?

Comment: It says permission is denied. I already ran it with sudo and it installed fine, it is just not working when I try to import it into a python file

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install cwiid
```

install in your virtual environment.

Comment: then you should be able to import , check if this one helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738196/installing-cwiid-with-python-3-extension

Comment: I finally was able to import after moving the files to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (it was in python2.7 before). However when I wanted to use it in my code it said that nothing could be found in the module. So I manually deleted it and now I am getting errors trying to reinstall with the line 'pip install cwiid'.